# Log console messages of a website when opened in safari of iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, safari

I have a website made in Javascript and HTML5

Hardware and software that I have

1. iPhone 4 (iOS 7)
2. Windows 7

In JS I have written some console message using Google console API.

When I open the website in safari in Windows 7, I can easily see the messages in console of developer tools, **but** when I open the website in safari in ios 7 in iphone, I can't see them. Is there a way I can see my console messages somewhere.

If there is tool please let me know which can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the web application that are made in JavaScript and HTML5, they can be debugged remotely using the tools that are available in the market/web for free, please find the list below

1. [jsconsole](http://jsconsole.com/)
2. [Aardwolf](http://lexandera.com/aardwolf/)

Both these tools are very helpful in remotely debugging the web application running on ios or Android.

Comment: Adding on thing to the answer, in jsconsole doesn't understand anything other than console.log, so if you are using console.group , then you need to use something else. Follow   http://stackoverflow.com/q/20876404/1258489 question for an answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this debugging using Safari for OSX with a connected iPhone.

Safari for OSX has a develop menu (which you can enable by going to preferences->advanced->Show develop menu). 
From this develop menu if you have an iPhone connected to your mac via USB you will see the phone listed. If safari is open on your phone, it will list "Safari" as a debugable mobile application.

From here, you can open websites on your phone and display the web inspector on safari which will display debug information of the page you loaded on your iPhone

Comment: @tgboneman. Understood, but I don't have Mac machine only windows 7